# How can I disable authentication for GET method in django modelviewset?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have written one router url and modelviewset like below:
**router.register(r'TestViewSet', views.TestViewSet)

**`class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): queryset = Test.objects.all() serializer_class = TestSerializer`
for this class, I want to disable authentication for GET method.
Pls give some solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to disable authentication only on the GET method of the `ModelViewSet`, we are required to override the permission class based on the HTTP method.

To achieve this, try following

```
from rest_framework import permissions

...

class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

...

def get_permissions(self):
    """Returns the permission based on the type of action"""

    if self.action == "list":
        return [permissions.AllowAny()]

    return [permissions.IsAuthenticated()]
```

In the above code, we are checking of the action (assuming you want to allow anyone to see the list, and limit who can perform other `actions`).

So if the action is `list` (HTTP method GET) it will allow anyone to access otherwise it will check for authentication.

Hope this answers your question.